# Trigger a height calc - jQuery Cycle2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle2

I've got a page using Cycle2 to run a slideshow with a hide show element to it.

It's all working great, except when I expand the slide and close it again, the height goes off. If I slightly resize the window, this will trigger the recalculation and then the space from the height gets put back right.

I'm using

```
data-cycle-auto-height="container"
```

I basically just need to trigger this action that happens on a resize.

Any tips?

Comment: How are you expanding/collapsing the slide? i.e. are you using jQuery slideUp, etc? Cycle2 adds the height property to the slide using the auto-height option, and therefore when hiding/collapsing it's likely you're losing the original height property set by Cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cheat way to do it would be to assign a listener to your plugin's open/close events that triggers a window resize.

```
$(window).on('your_event_name', function() {
  $(this).resize();
});
```

If you've got the time though, you should dig in a little deeper and figure out what's actually happening. Ideally, your plugin would handle this stuff on it's own.

Comment: Yeah that's essentially how I'm doing it at the moment - might be the only way I reckon.

Comment: It should be `$(this).resize()` or `$(window).resize()` (`TypeError: window.resize is not a function`).